# How to make an https request?

Tags: json, spring, https

I should make a request to the address and send json, json I have in the form of a model

```
public class RequestToPlanfix {
    private String cmd;
    private String providerId;
    private String channel;
    private String chatId;
    private String planfix_token;
    private String message;
    private String title;
    private String contactId;
    private String contactName;
    private String contactLastName;
    private String contactIco;
    private String contactEmail;
    private String contactPhone;
    private String contactData;
    @Convert(converter = Attachments.class)
    private Map<String,String> name;
    @Convert(converter = Attachments.class)
    private Map<String,String> url;
    private Boolean isEcho;
}
```

that is, I should send json via https whose fields match the fields of this entity, how can I get and translate this entity into json? How can I make an https request further?

then I will receive the answer in the form of json, the fields of which are the fields of the next entity

that is, I will get json and I should do it parse

```
public class RequestFromPlanfix {
    private String cmd;
    private String providerId;
    private String chatId;
    private String contactPhone;
    private String channel;
    private String token;
    private String message;
    private String userName;
    private String userLastName;
    private String userIco;
    private String taskEmail;
    @Convert(converter = Attachments.class)
    private Map<String,String> name;
    @Convert(converter = Attachments.class)
    private Map<String,String> url;
}
```

the fields in two cases are different in some places, so I created two entities, then when we send the request we will send the first json, and when we receive the answer the second json, I cannot understand how to make the request and associate the json with the entity, thank you

[image]

```
   String postUrl = "www.site.com";
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(postUrl);
    StringEntity postingString = new StringEntity(gson.toJson(requestToPlanfix));//gson.tojson() converts your pojo to json
    post.setEntity(postingString);
    post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
```

Comment: Ok got your question, can you tell me are you already using something to serialize/de-serialize POJO to JSON like jackson?If not , are you open to use? Also, do you have your json request and response structure? Let me know accordingly I'll add my answer. Thanks.

Comment: check please my changes

Comment: ok you're using GSON. Understood you created 2 model/entities one for JSON Request and another for JSON Response..which is good. Then you can use spring `restTemplate` to make the call. Can help  but please add your expected JSON and request JSON as well to your question please. 
I mean JSON like : { "cmd":"John", "providerId":30, "channel":null }

Comment: @Camnp added as answer, please see if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to make a `HTTP POST` call.

And as it is explained your `request` body looks like `RequestToPlanfix.java` and your expected `Response` will be like `RequestFromPlanfix.java`.

Furthermore, you're using `GSON` for transformation.

Now I'll advise you to re-define your models (`RequestToPlanfix.java` & `RequestFromPlanfix.java`) as :

- Go to  : http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/
- Paste your `JSON` request first and choose `GSON, Java` and any additional field you think is valid.
- Then Generate your Plain Old Java Objects from there.
- This way we're sure nothing wrong in our JSON - JAVA understanding.
- Likewise, based on `response` JSON you're expecting, generate your `RequestFromPlanfix.java`.
- Replace your existing POJOs with the ones generated above.

Now , lets make the `HTTP call` using Spring's `RestTemplate` :

```
public class MakeRestCall {

  @Autowired
  private RestTemplate restTemplate;

  public void getResponse(){

      String postUrl = "www.site.com";

      // get your request object ready
      RequestToPlanfix requestObject = getRequestObject();

      // initialize HttpEntity 
      HttpEntity<RequestToPlanfix> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestObject);
      ResponseEntity<RequestFromPlanfix> response = restTemplate.exchange(postUrl, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, RequestFromPlanfix.class);
      RequestFromPlanfix responseObject = response.getBody();
      // carry-on with your other stuff
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RestTemplate.

Something like:

```
@Test 
public void test() throws URISyntaxException {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    final String baseUrl = "https://your_url!";
    final URI uri = new URI(baseUrl);

    final RequestToPlanfix requestToPlanfix = new RequestToPlanfix();
    // set fields here to requestToPlanfix 

    final ResponseEntity<RequestFromPlanfix> result = restTemplate.postForEntity(uri, requestToPlanfix, String.class);

    // your response 
    final RequestFromPlanfix requestFromPlanfix = result.getBody();

    //Verify request succeed
    Assert.assertEquals(200, result.getStatusCodeValue()); 
 }
```

Other examples you can find [here](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot2/resttemplate-post-json-example/)

Comment: and you write a test, I do not quite understand you, and how does my essence go into json?

Comment: @СамирШахмурадлы  your essence go into json thanks [jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson), it automatically bind java object to json, and json to object.